# How many times this nested loop will run, mathematically?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the number of times this nested loop will run, **mathematically**.

```
//Nested Loop (A)
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```

I know that this loop will run ((n)(n + 1))/2. But when I'm trying to calculate it mathematically the results seem to turn out different.

For example:

```
//<This nested loop will run m x n times.
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

In the Nested Loop (A):

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) //<this outer loop will run n times.
```

Now it can be seen that the inner loop will run i times:

```
         for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```

In each iteration the value of i is different.

I tried using the formula to find the sum of the arithmetic series:

```
         1 + 2 + 3 + .... + n = (n(n + 1))/2
```

But that results in:

```
         outer loop's iteration = n
         inner loop's iteration = (n ( n + 1 ) ) / 2

         total iterations = n ( n ( n + 1 ) ) / 2
                          = n ^ 2 ( n + 1 ) / 2      ///< which is WAY MORE than n ( n + 1 ) / 2
```

What am I doing wrong in calculating total iterations?

--
Thanks :)

**EDIT:** I have posted the answer.

Comment: I believe the first example would be O(n*log(n)) and the second would be O(n^2).

Comment: If you're not sure then why not try compiling it and running it ?

Comment: @David I didn't ask for Big O but thanks for replying.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for replying. Obviously, I compiled and ran it before asking this question. That's why I know it should run (n)(n + 1)/2 times.

Comment: OK - but if you're having trouble rationalising theory with practice you could try adding some debug `cout`s to the test code and confirm whether your analysis is correct.

Comment: The first one will loop infinite number of times as you have `j=n` ,provided that `n!=0`

Comment: @PaulR - Already done that first.

Comment: @CoolGuy oops typo mistake.

Comment: OK - I would have thought that if you try it with a small n, e.g. 3, then it should be pretty simple to analyse.

Comment: @PaulR The problem wasn't that. The problem was that I was having trouble in calculating it "mathematically". I appreciate your help. I have figured it out myself but before I accept it as an "Answer", kindly review it so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

I was using the sum of arithmetic series formula to calculate its(inner loop) "total" iterations which in this case actually provided me with the total iterations of the nested loop.

Both of these two methods should provide the correct answer:

### Method 1

Simply calculate the number of iterations of the inner loop by using Sum of Arithmetic series formula.

The inner loop iteration series and its sum is:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + .... + n = n(n + 1)/2
```

This will give the total iterations of the nested loop.

### Method 2

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) //< This will run 'n' times
```

We find this average number of iterations:

```
   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) //< Average = (n + 1)/2
```

So now total number of iterations of nested loop = n * (n + 1)/2

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```

For each value of i = n, inner loop would execute 'n' times. That means number of times inner loop would be executed is :-

```
n * (n + 1)/2
```

which is same as *total number of iterations*.

Answer (score 0):

infinite times

since  j = n is equivalent to 1 in all cases.

if you meant j==n it will look something like this...

1 2 3 4 5
  2 3 4 5
    3 4 5
      4 5
        5

that function is called the sum of natural numbers 5+4+3+2+1 = 15

that means it will be N(N+1)*2 time complexity.

N(N+1)*2 5+4+3+2+1 = 5*6*2 = 15

Comment: you mean `/2` not `*2`